# Codeigniter Active Record Does Not Match PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have this code.

```
 $correct_spot = rand(1,10);
 $data = array(
                    'current_correct_answer' => $correct_spot                   
                );



                $this->db->update('demo_user_profiles', $data, array('upro_id' => $user_id));

                $query = $this->db->get_where('demo_user_profiles', array('upro_id' => $user_id));
                $result = $query->result();
                print_r($result);
```

On this page, the $correct_spot number is printed out, inserted, then retrieved and reprinted. It all works fine. However, if I look in PHPmyadmin it has the wrong value for $correct_spot sometimes, as if it evaluates the whole thing again. This is a problem as when I retrieve the value on another page it is different to what I put in. Am I doing something wrong? The MySQL field is simply an int(11).

Thanks in advance.

Relevant controller code is for "question"

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -  
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // To load the CI benchmark and memory usage profiler - set 1==1.
    if (1==2)
    {
        $sections = array(
            'benchmarks' => TRUE, 'memory_usage' => TRUE,
            'config' => FALSE, 'controller_info' => FALSE, 'get' => FALSE, 'post' => FALSE, 'queries' => FALSE,
            'uri_string' => FALSE, 'http_headers' => FALSE, 'session_data' => FALSE
        );
        $this->output->set_profiler_sections($sections);
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    }

    // Load required CI libraries and helpers.
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');

    // IMPORTANT! This global must be defined BEFORE the flexi auth library is loaded!
    // It is used as a global that is accessible via both models and both libraries, without it, flexi auth will not work.
    $this->auth = new stdClass;

    // Load 'standard' flexi auth library by default.
    $this->load->library('flexi_auth');

    // Check user is logged in via either password or 'Remember me'.
    // Note: Allow access to logged out users that are attempting to validate a change of their email address via the 'update_email' page/method.
    if (! $this->flexi_auth->is_logged_in() && $this->uri->segment(2) != 'update_email')
    {
        // Set a custom error message.
        $this->flexi_auth->set_error_message('You must login to access this area.', TRUE);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->flexi_auth->get_messages());
        redirect('auth');
    }

    // Note: This is only included to create base urls for purposes of this demo only and are not necessarily considered as 'Best practice'.
    $this->load->vars('base_url', 'http://cloudtute.com/');
    $this->load->vars('includes_dir', 'http://cloudtute.com/includes/');
    $this->load->vars('current_url', $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(1));

    // Define a global variable to store data that is then used by the end view page.
    $this->data = null;
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('home');
}

function dashboard()
{
    // Get any status message that may have been set.
    $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');

    $this->load->view('dashboard', $this->data);
}

function question()
{
    // Get any status message that may have been set.
    $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');

    $this->load->view('question', $this->data);
}

function answer()
{
    // Get any status message that may have been set.
    $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');

    //Get question answer
    $username = $this->input->post("variable_serial");
    $this->data['questiontest']=$username;

    $question_id = $this->input->post("question_id");
    $this->data['question_id'] = $question_id;


    $this->load->view('answer', $this->data);
}




function elements()
{
    // Get any status message that may have been set.
    $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');

    $this->load->view('elements', $this->data);
}

}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

Header code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by JetBrains PhpStorm.
 * User: Randy
 * Date: 29/04/13
 * Time: 13:37
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 7)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 8)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 9)]><html class="no-js ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

    <!-- Meta Tags -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title>Ace HSC Maths</title>

    <meta name="description" content="" />

    <!-- Mobile Specifics -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320"/>

    <!-- Mobile Internet Explorer ClearType Technology -->
    <!--[if IEMobile]>  <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">  <![endif]-->

    <!-- Standard Bootstrap -->


    <!-- Standard Bootstrap -->


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="<?php echo asset_url();?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Revolution Slider -->
    <link href="<?php echo asset_url();?>rs-plugin/css/settings.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Main Style -->
    <link href="<?php echo asset_url();?>css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FancyBox -->
    <link href="<?php echo asset_url();?>css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font Icons -->
    <link href="<?php echo asset_url();?>css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Shortcodes -->
    <link href="<?php echo asset_url();?>/css/shortcodes.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Responsive -->
    <link href="<?php echo asset_url();?>/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo asset_url();?>/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Fav Icon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="#">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="#">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="#">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="#">

    <!-- Modernizr -->
    <script src="<?php echo asset_url();?>/js/modernizr.js"></script>

    <!-- Analytics -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'Replace Your Analytics Code']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
    <!-- End Analytics -->

    <!-- Highcharts
   ================================================== -->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>




    <!--new Mathjax stuff-->
    <style>
        .MathJax_Display .MathJax,
        DIV.MathJax_MathML math,
        .MathJax_SVG_Display .MathJax_SVG {
            display: inline-block ! important;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            padding: 10px ! important;
            border: 0px dashed white ! important;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config(
        {
        tex2jax:
        {inlineMath: [['%%%%','%%%%'], ['??','??']],
        displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['@@', '@@']]
        }
        }
        );
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
    </script>

    <!--new Mathjax stuff-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                chart: {
                   // backgroundColor: {
                   //     linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
                   //     stops: [
                   //         [0, 'rgb(213, 211, 206)'],
                   //         [1, 'rgb(213, 211, 206)']
                   //     ]
                   // },
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    //plotBackgroundColor: 'rgb(124, 143, 125)',
                    plotShadow: false,
                    plotBorderWidth: 0
                },

                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                colors: [
                    '#323A45',
                    '#E41B17',
                    '#FF8330',
                    '#8bbc21',
                    '#910000',
                    '#1aadce',
                    '#492970',
                    '#f28f43',
                    '#77a1e5',
                    '#c42525',
                    '#a6c96a'
                ]
            });
            var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'dashboardchart',
                    type: 'spline'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        lineWidth: 5,
                        marker: {
                            fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                            lineWidth: 2,
                            radius: 6,
                            lineColor: null // inherit from series
                        }
                    }
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                        month: '%e %b',
                        year: '%b'
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Ability Score (out of 100)',
                        style: {
                            color: '#323A45',
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }
                    },
                    min: 0
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b', this.x) +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Overall Ability',
                    // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
                    // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
                    // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
                    data: [
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  0,  1), 50.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  0, 10), 51.2],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  2, 12), 63.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  3,  1), 59.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  3, 10), 58.2],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  3, 18), 57.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  3, 28), 62.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  4, 11), 67.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  5,  1), 72.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  5, 20), 84.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  6, 13), 82.0],
                    ]

                }, {
                    name: 'Target',
                    data: [
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  0,  1), 80.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  1,  1), 80.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  2,  1), 80.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  3,  1), 80.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  4,  1), 80.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  5,  1), 80.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  6,  1), 80.0],
                        [Date.UTC(2013,  7,  1), 80.0]
                    ],
                    dashStyle: 'longdash',
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }]

            });
        });
    </script>


</head>




<body>

<!-- Header -->
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="index.html" title="Ace HSC Maths"><font color="#E41B17">A<sup>+</sup></font>ce HSC Maths</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="span9">
                <!-- Mobile Menu -->
                <a id="mobile-nav" class="menu-nav" href="#menu-nav"><span class="menu-icon"></span></a>

                <!-- Standard Menu -->
                <nav id="menu">
                    <ul id="menu-nav">
                        <li><a href="http://www.cloudtute.com">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="elements.html">Features</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu arrow-up">
                                <li><a href="full-width.html">Full Width</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="team.html">Our Team</a></li>
                                <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                                <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
                                <li><a href="retina-icons.html">Retina Icons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="footer-widgets.html">Footer Widgets</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="http://www.cloudtute.com/auth/"><i style ="margin-top: 3px" class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Not Logged In</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu arrow-up">
                                <li><a href="full-width.html">Full Width</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="team.html">Our Team</a></li>
                                <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                                <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
                                <li><a href="retina-icons.html">Retina Icons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="footer-widgets.html">Footer Widgets</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- End Header -->
```

Comment: what do you mean by value from another page?

Comment: The value in the database is not the same as the value being input.

Comment: where you able to pinpoint when this problem occurs? does it occur always or only when something done specifically?

Comment: Always occur. When I print the information when inputting it (as above and reprint out the database info) it is as intended. However, the database seems to store a different value (as if another random number is generated.

Comment: It works fine if I am inputting a static value - e.g. if $correct_spot = 8; it is always correct. It only seems to reevaluate $correct_spot when inputting it into the database for some reason.

Comment: your code seems correct. the random value is stored in variable $data and then used through out the code. So theoretically vale of $data should not change till the script is re-executed.

Comment: It looks like the code is executing twice for some reason. I am not sure why as it is only called once. But CodeIgniter seems to update the database twice.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine. The value shown as output is the one inserted into database table. I tried using Codeigniter.

Comment: May be you are calling the model more than once from your controller.

Comment: It's like the whole view is loading twice, once where it displays stuff on the page, the second time where it inserts stuff into the database that doesn't match the data on the page.

Comment: Can you please paste your controller codes.

Comment: I think its something in the header section. I've replaced the code to simply add one to the value in the database. And with the header it increments by 2 on each refresh and without only by 1.

Comment: may be it is. The controller looks ok. Can you paste the header codes.

Comment: header code added. I'm not sure why any of this should cause all of the database queries in the view to run twice!?

Comment: your header is also fine. In the controller which is posted here, on which line are you calling the model?

Comment: For some reason, John, I think it might be this bit of the header:           <!-- Fav Icon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="#">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="#">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="#">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="#">             If I remove this bit then it only happens once on each page. I really don't understand what is going on!

Comment: That seems to have solved it - but now I am more confused than before!!!

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense but just include this line `<!-- Fav Icon --> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="#"> ` and replace # with some other url and try executing the code.

Comment: I included those <link> to my view head and executed the script. It works fine.

Comment: Ok thanks - putting in a different URL to "#" works. Any idea why this is? I don't really understand the problem - is it trying to load the favicon and somehow reloading the page because of the "#" link?

Comment: To be frank i am also confused. To my knowledge # shouldn't cause any trouble but i guess the page is silently reloading or doing something else in your case. Even more confusing part is when I didn't replace #, the script worked fine.

Comment: Ah ok. Well thanks anyway for your help - I don't think I'd have been able to fix it otherwise. Again not sure why!

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).